# cartesian product of two data sources

Tags: ssis, etl, dataflow

Let's say I have two data sources in SSIS.

Table A has 10 rows and two of the columns are empty. 
Table B has 20 rows with two columns each.

I want to somehow join them in an ETL process in a specific way: 
for each row of table A, 20 rows are generated with the values for the two columns from table B.

This way 200 rows should be generated with every possible combination of the rows from tables A and B

I tried using Merge Join and Union  pieces, but they won't work... Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an identical column to both the sources and assign it the same value, say 1. So all the 10 rows in table1 and 20 rows in table2 have the value of "1" for that column. When you now do a `merge join`, keeping the join type as `full outer join`, *Voila!*, you have your `cross join`. Do keep in mind, the sources need to be sorted on that column for `SSIS` to go ahead with the `Merge join`, else it would throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2...
FROM  table1, table2
```

A cartesian join is a cross join in MS-SQL world.

Use cross join without a where clause

A step-by-step in SSIS for cross join:
http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.be/2010/09/performing-cross-join-cartesian-product.html

Some SQL Server documentation about cross join:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: How to apply your answer to an ETL data flow?

Comment: maybe this will help you  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/33aa6d18-1be1-4c66-8e63-a853fb275671/is-cross-join-possible-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.be/2010/09/performing-cross-join-cartesian-product.html  a more detailed guide