# ssis how to add all columns from another source without join criteria?

Tags: merge, ssis, lookup

I want to read properties from my source file, and the add the properties to all records in the file itself

So I'd like to join the Element reading the FileProperties to all rows from the data...

```
Data1 FileProperty1 Fileproperty2
Data2 FileProperty1 FileProperty2
```

In fact, I just want to add the columns from the property dataset, to each row from the data... how can I do that ? I try merge and lookup, but I don't have any Id to match witch, just need to append...

Comment: Unclear.  How are these properties being introduced to the dataflow?   Through a source component?  Variables?  What do they look like?    Give an example of your source data, properties, and final desired results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cartesian product of two data sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560208/cartesian-product-of-two-data-sources)

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51968374/10255436) for a similar problem.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no SSIS component to get file property information. However, I suggest a script task in control flow saving those properties to variables and then using a derived column to add those variables to your data flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create your file property variables
2. Add a script task to control flow:
3. Add variables as read/write
4. Add the following script (I gave you 1 property as an example)

   ```
   System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo("[Your File Path]");
   Dts.Variables["FileSize"].Value = fi.Length;
   ```
5. Add your dataflow and connect to script task (script first)
6. Add a derived column to DF and add additional columns for your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use your property file as a source to a pivot transform to transform the rows into a list of columns. Now that you have all the properties in a single row, simply use the pivot output as a source, and use merge transform to merge these new columns with the other file.

More info on how to use [Pivot transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/pivot-transformation?view=sql-server-2017)